# Bootstrap style button exactly as link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to style a button identically to how a link would look. This is as close as I got:

[image]

```
<p>Hello <a href="aoeu">how</a> are you</p>
<p>Hello <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-inline">how</button> are you</p>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqvjyJ

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add the `align-baseline` class...

`<button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-inline align-baseline">how</button>`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgJjdr

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed check the code or link below.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Hello <a href="aoeu">how</a> are you</p>
<p>Hello <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-inline">how</button> are you</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p .btn-link {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

https://codepen.io/dev_aman/pen/RexYoa